# How to convert data from two tables get from Linq query to List witch can be populated in wpf form

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, mvvm, entity-framework-6

I don't know how to convert `LINQ` query to List type of Owner with data from Transport table and pass it to WPF form (using MVVM)

DB structure :

Owner has many cars, so I described relation like this:

```
public partial class Transport
    {
        public Transport()
        {
          TransportOwners = new List<TransportOwner>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int TransportID { get; set; }

        public string PlateNo { get; set; }

        public string Brand { get; set; }

        public string Model { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<TransportOwner> TransportOwners { get; set; }
    }

public partial class Owner
    {
        [Key]
        public int OwnerID { get; set; }

        public int TransportID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("TransportID")]
        public virtual Transport Transport { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string PlateNo { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string Brand { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string Model { get; set; }
    }
```

In ViewModel I created list type of Owner :

```
    private List<Owner> _haveList;
    public List<Owner> HaveList
    {
        get { return _haveList; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _haveList)
            {
                _haveList = value;
                RaisePropertiesChanged("HaveList");
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I am trying to get the data :

```
 using (var dbContext = new DataModelContext())
                    {
                        var query = dbContext.Owners.AsQueryable();


    query = query.Where(o => o.OwnerId.Equal(OwnerParameter));
query = query.Select(t => new 
                            {
                                Model = t.Transport.Model,
                                Brand = t.Transport.Brand,
                                PlateNo = t.Transport.PlateNo
                            }).ToList();
```

// Here I see data I need (list of Transport by Owner)

```
HaveList = query;

'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: ... >>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DataModels.Owner>'
```

Comment: You want to convert an anonymous type to a typed one.
Read my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linq-to-Entities you can only project to an anonymous type or a regular class. You can't project to an existing entity type

```
        var result = (from o in query 
                      where o.OwnerID==OwnerParameter
                     select new OwnerModel
                     {
                         Model=o.Transport.Model,
                         Brand=o.Transport.Brand
                     }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

1 - You should try to use a named object

```
HaveList= query.Select(t => new OwnerModel
                        {
                            Model = t.Transport.Model,
                            Brand = t.Transport.Brand,
                            PlateNo = t.Transport.PlateNo
                        }).ToList();
```

2 - Your query object is created as IQuerible, then you try to assign it as a List

query = query should not work I think.

Note that OwnerModel should fire INotificationEvent when one of the property is modified :)

```
private List<OwnerModel> _haveList;
    public List<OwnerModel> HaveList
    {
        get { return _haveList; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _haveList)
            {
                _haveList = value;
                RaisePropertiesChanged("HaveList");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank You, I've tryed this, but then I get error: {"The entity or complex type 'DataModels.Owner' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."}

Comment: Did you create a new Class OwenerModel as I suggested it? :)

Comment: I don't need a new class... I have Not Mapped fields in Owner class

Comment: I wanted create List without creating new class :)

Comment: Ok, But take care about the notification Properties, some changed should not be reflected :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have what I need, thank You for Your help

```
List<Owner> list = DBContext.Owners.Where(to => to.OwnerID == ownerParameter).ToList();

HaveList = list.Select(t => new Owner()
                    {
                        Model = t.Transport.Model,
                        Brand = t.Transport.Brand,
                        PlateNo = t.Transport.PlateNo
                    }).ToList();
```